# If I use yum am I a system administrator?

Tags: linux, security, yum, system-administration

I'm thinking of moving from shared hosting to a VPS or dedicated server. The thing I worry most about is keeping the system patched. I do have some linux experience and know that there are commands to keep the system up to date, like 'yum update'.

Is it naive to think that I could maintain a secure linux host by just periodically running 'yum update'?

EDIT: I'm assuming that SSH connections via some tool like putty, proper use of system users and groups to own processes and files, etc. What I've always wondered about is what sys admins mean when they talk about always patching systems. I understand a patch to be a diff that can be applied to source to build a new binary with a fix included. It seems like that is mostly handled using automated tools these days.

Comment: You also need Iron Maiden T-shirts ;) On my experience, yum is used on System Administration. Of course, test on DEV servers firstly and check with Security people so that it is clear that you are not getting dangerous updates.

Comment: That, always connect via SSH, use a strong password, and configure everything just right.

Comment: I'll start looking for some heavy metal band t-shirts.